# Create Multiple check boxes in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I need to create multiple check boxes in S2 like below.

[image]

Using this code I'm only getting single check box

```
public class EmployeeListBean {
private String empCode = null;
private String empName = null;
public EmployeeListBean(String empCode,String empName)
{
   //constructor
}
//setter and getter methods
}
```

In action class

```
public ArrayList<EmployeeListBean> getListOfEmployees()
{
    return listOfEmployees;
}
```

In execute()

```
    listOfEmployees = new ArrayList<EmployeeListBean>();
    listOfEmployees.add(new EmployeeListBean("1", "Smith"));
```

In JSP,

```
 <s:iterator value="listOfEmployees">
 <s:checkbox name="someselectedname" label="%{empName}"  fieldValue="%{empCode}"/><br/>
 </s:iterator>
```

I'm following normal way. Here I want to select only one check box among three check boxes. So we can do it in JS or Jquery. In HTML, it's like

```
  <label>abc:&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
  <br/>
  <label>def:&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="ballet1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ballet1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ballet1" />
```

But I want above format. How to do this in S2.

Comment: If you want to select only one checkbox out of three then I recommend to use radio button instead of checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution for this. According to my need here I need to change some field value to get corresponding check box value.

In JSP:

```
   <s:iterator value="listOfEmployees">
   <s:property value="%{empName}" />&nbsp;
   <s:checkbox name="someselectedname%{empCode}" fieldValue="%{empCode}" theme="simple"/>&nbsp;
   <s:checkbox name="someselectedname%{empCode}" fieldValue="%{empCode}" theme="simple"/>&nbsp;
   <s:checkbox name="someselectedname%{empCode}" fieldValue="%{empCode}" theme="simple"/><br/>
   </s:iterator>
```

In JS:

```
   $(':checkbox').on('change',function(){
   var th = $(this), name = th.prop('name'); 
   if(th.is(':checked')){
   $(':checkbox[name="'  + name + '"]').not($(this)).prop('checked',false);   
   }
   });
```

Is there any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<s:iterator value="listOfEmployees">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bus"> I have a bus<br>
 </s:iterator>
```

Comment: By using this code one can select two check boxes among four. I want only one @xrcwrn.

Comment: If you want to select only one then use redio button.